# Junit test Cases Failed in Eclipse but mvn clean install shows sucess

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

When I manually run  test cases in Eclipse, one specific junit test case always fails. I even know the reason behind its failure.

Now the problem is that when i´I run the command in a terminal
 : `mvn clean install`

It shows build was successful, but it should have failed ?
Can anyone please explain me the logic behind this.

Comment: Do you see this test running when you run maven?

Comment: Are you sure your maven actually runs the tests? Your `mvn` command does not say anything about the tests, maybe your `pom.xml` does? Have a look at the apache maven plugin if there is some configuration like `<skipTests>true</skipTests>`.

Comment: There are too many possible errors causing this, how can we guess without seeing any code?

Comment: Maven test plugins may not pick up your test if it doesn't conform to some rather obtuse rules.  Inspect the output from the test phase very carefully.

Comment: @NirLevy yes i can see this test running during maven build.

Comment: @GameDroids no i haven't skipped test cases during maven build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Guys problem is solved for me,I have tried to enable assertion in pom.xml, and it worked for me.

-ea

Thank you for the help.